# Difficulty understand logic

Tags: math, logic

Ok so I have to prove the following sequent:

```
(p -> r) ^ (q -> r) |- p ^ q -> r
```

I understand why that is clearly correct and I also understand the rules of natural deduction.  What I don't understand is how I go about proving it.  Here is the model answer provided:

```
1. (p -> r) ^ (q -> r) |- p ^ q -> r     premise
2. p ^ q                                 assumption
3. p                                     ^e 2
4. p -> r                                ^e 1
5. r                                     ->e 4,3
6. p ^ q -> r                            ->i 2,5

(e = elimination / i = introduction).
```

Could someone provide me with a link or a 'dumbed-down' explanation? I feel like I am missing a simple concept that is causing this to be hard to understand... ?

For example, on line 4, why does it require the p from line 3 to remove the ->, where as in line 3, you can remove the ^ q without using a q?

I am sure this is quite straight forward but it doesn't seem to make sense to me... ?

Comment: +1 for supplying a good example of how to ask a homework question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In line 2, you have `p ^ q` which means that both `p` and `q` are true. From that follows that `p` is true, because if both of them are true, then any single one is also true.

In line 4, `r` is true only if `p` is true. And in line 3 you have that `p` is true. Therefore, `r` is also true.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the ^ q without using q because p ^ q means p AND q -- p is true independent of q.

You can't remove the p -> without using p because p -> r means p IMPLIES r -- r is only guaranteed to be true if p is as well.